# How do I remove all default Webkit search field styling?

Tags: css, search, input, textbox, webkit

By default, `<input type="search" />` renders like a "native" search field on Mac OS X (rounded corners, clear button, etc.). I want to completely remove this custom styling so that the input looks identical to an equivalent text input (`<input type="text" />`), but while keeping the input type set to `search`.

I've tried `-webkit-appearance: none;`, which gets it very close...but there's something funny going on with margins/padding that I can't seem to override, which causes the width of the search field to render ~20px shorter than a text input.

Is there another `-webkit-` specific property I'm not aware of to totally disable the styling?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Try these stylings:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/#comment-82432

Comment: instead of `display: none;` you can also use `-webkit-appearance:none;` which keeps this crazy vendor prefix rule in it's own space.

Comment: Note that this fixes the outline issues addressed in some common style resets with `outline-offset: -2px;`. With these rules, the `outline-offset` is not needed.

Answer (score 20):

For those that still need to support IE, it's worth mentioning that you need an *entirely different* set of vendor styles to remove the '×' from Internet Explorer

Per the article [Remove the X from Internet Explorer and Chrome input type search](https://blog.maximerouiller.com/post/remove-the-x-from-internet-explorer-and-chrome-input-type-search/):

```css
/* clears the 'X' from Internet Explorer */
input.hide-clear[type=search]::-ms-clear,
input.hide-clear[type=search]::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; 
}

/* clears the 'X' from Chrome */
input.hide-clear[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input.hide-clear[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input.hide-clear[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input.hide-clear[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none; 
}
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets & [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/bhd7u81L/)

```css
label, input {display: block; margin-bottom: 1rem;}

/* clears the 'X' from Internet Explorer */
input.hide-clear[type=search]::-ms-clear,
input.hide-clear[type=search]::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; 
}

/* clears the 'X' from Chrome */
input.hide-clear[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input.hide-clear[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input.hide-clear[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input.hide-clear[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<label >
  default
  <input type="search" value="query">  
</label>


<label >
  without x
  <input type="search" value="query" class="hide-clear" >  
</label>
```

Comment: I would like to add to this answer, its important to keep the IE and Chrome rules separately as they are in this example. If you combine all 6 together, Chrome wouldn't understand IE's rules and vice versa, which in turn makes the whole rule set ignored in both browsers

Answer (score 6):

As of 2023, this can be simplified.

Firefox search field appears as a text field.
Only Chrome and Safari change the search field appearance.

- Remove cancel button (Chrome & Safari):

```
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  appearance: none;
}
```

- Remove Safari left inner padding under macOS or the magnifying glass on the left under iOS:

```
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  appearance: none;
}
```

- Both:

```
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  appearance: none;
}
```

- Make the search field to be displayed like a text field under Safari:

```
[type="search"] {
  appearance: textfield;
  outline-offset: -2px; /* Fix outline style in Safari */
}
```

(source: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/8.0.1/normalize.css#L285-L293)

The `-2px` "breaks" Chrome :-/

- Some explanations:

[`-webkit-search-results-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-results-button) and `-webkit-search-results-decoration` are not needed because [Chrome >= 53 (released in 2016)](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-53-deprecations/#remove-results-attribute-for-input-typesearch) does not support the `results` attribute anymore.

Chrome 117 shadow DOM uses only one pseudo-element [`-webkit-search-cancel-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button) which is specific to `input type="search"`:

[image: input type="search" Chrome 117 shadow DOM]

In addition Safari 17.0 shadow DOM uses `-webkit-search-decoration` which adds a left inner padding under macOS 13.6 or a magnifying glass on the left under iOS 17.0:

[image: input type="search" Safari 17.0 shadow DOM]

Demo:

```css
[type="search"].no-cancel-button::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  appearance: none;
}

[type="search"].no-decoration::-webkit-search-decoration {
  appearance: none;
}

[type="search"].no-decoration-no-cancel-button::-webkit-search-decoration,
[type="search"].no-decoration-no-cancel-button::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  appearance: none;
}

[type="search"].as-textfield {
  appearance: textfield;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="input type='search'">

<br><br>

<input type="search" class="no-cancel-button" placeholder="no cancel button">

<br><br>

<input type="search" class="no-decoration" placeholder="no decoration">

<br><br>

<input type="search" class="no-decoration-no-cancel-button" placeholder="no decoration no cancel button">

<br><br>

<input type="search" class="as-textfield" placeholder="as textfield">

<br><br>

<input type="text" placeholder="input type='text'">
```