# input type search hide the icons

Tags: html

In chrome, when I type in a search field, there appears a **cross** which clears the field when clicked (one can also use <kbd>Esc</kbd> for this).

```html
  <input type="search">
```

Is there any way to hide this cross?

---

**EDIT:**

If you use attribute `results="2"`, it starts showing a magnifying glass too. what kind of sorcery is this? Why does the glass shows up when I use the `results` attribute?

```html
<input type="search" results="2">
```

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome too, but (at least the fiddle example) doesn't show a cross. Just a box. _What Google Chrome version are you using?_ (for me: Google Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m)

Comment: You need to start typing to see it

Comment: @Frithjof - if you type in the box the X appears

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove all default Webkit search field styling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421551/how-do-i-remove-all-default-webkit-search-field-styling)

Comment: Check out this page, might help :)

[http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/]

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Sourabh you will need to disable WebKit’s proprietary pseudo elements

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}
```

Let me know if this helps

For your case use:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="search">
```

Comment: Why all the unnessecary CSS-references?