# Stop LastPass filling out a form

Tags: html, forms, lastpass

Is there a way to prevent the LastPass browser extension from filling out a HTML-based form with an input field with the name "username"?

This is an hidden field, so I don't want any software to use this field for their purposes:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="checkusername" maxlength="9" value="1999" class="longinput" style="display:none">
```

The solution should not be like "rename the input field".

Comment: If the field is hidden, it's better to set `type="hidden"` instead of hide it with CSS

Comment: super simple `$(':input').attr('data-lpignore', true);` Thats all. This will diable lastpass form filling on all the forms.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Adding

```
data-lpignore="true"
```

to an input field disabled the grey LastPass [...] box for me.

Sourced from [LastPass.com](https://support.logmeininc.com/lastpass/help/manage-your-form-fills-lp040002)

Comment: This should be the valid answer. LP seems to respect this attribute and does not require any crazy "search" names or ids or roles.

Comment: this only removes grey icon, but does not stop LastPass to ignore input autofill

Comment: this should NOT be the accepted answer since this does NOT "Stop LastPass filling out a form"

Comment: Per the link provided in the answer (https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=10512) , LP only prevents the icon from being displayed on that field

Comment: According to the LastPass documentation this should work. https://support.logmeininc.com/lastpass/help/manage-your-form-fills-lp040002. Quote: "To prevent LastPass from autofilling certain fields on specific sites or applications that you have control over, you can edit your item(s) to add the 'data-lpignore'=true attribute within those form fields which you do not want to autofill."

Comment: Tried this in 2020 and it DOES stop LastPass from auto filling the input field that has this data attribute.

Comment: Reiterating other recent comments... LastPass seems to have improved/fixed this since the comments made in 2017 & 2018 saying that it doesn't stop autofill. It **definitely does** stop autofill now (Dec 2020).

Comment: I also found that lastpass in 2021 was overwriting my autocomplete values, including "new-password" without setting data-lpignore="true". I also have set the value in the extension to respect autocomplete="off"

Comment: It is also worth noting that you'll have to set `data-lpignore="true"` on each input element that you want to be ignored. Simply adding it to the wrapping <form> in the expectation it will ignore all inner inputs won't work. Thanks Obama.

Comment: With the `v4.104.0` release in November '22 (https://lastpass.com/upgrade.php) this does not seem to work any longer.

Comment: Looks to me that if you disable the "Use improved Save and Fill" Advanced Option in the LastPass vault itthe data-lpignore=true attribute still works. Will check if there is already a bug report on this.

Answer (score 81):

Three conditions have to be met:

1. The *form* (not the element) needs to have `autocomplete="off"` attribute
2. *Input* fields need to have the attribute `data-lpignore="true"`
3. Lastpass *user* needs to have this option enabled:

   - (old) `Settings > Advanced > Allow pages to disable autofill`
   - (new) `Account Options > Extension Preferences > Advanced > Respect AutoComplete=off: allow websites to disable Autofill`

So this depends on both user and the developer.

[Official documentation from LastPass](https://support.lastpass.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=lastpass&topicId=LastPass/c_lp_prevent_fields_from_being_filled_automatically.html&_LANG=enus) confirms this method is the way to go.

Comment: Is this still accurate? I cannot find the setting to allow pages to disable autofill in any of the settings menus in LastPass.

Comment: In newer versions the setting can be found at Account Options > Extension Preferences > Advanced > "Respect AutoComplete=off: allow websites to disable Autofill"

Comment: I cant even find Account Options in my Chrome extension. All I have is Account Settings and Advanced Options. In neither spot I find any an Respect AutoComplete=off option....

Comment: I have found simply putting `autocomplete="off"` on the form elements you wish to disable works fine. You'll still need to do step 3 above, however you don't have to place `autocomplete="off"` on the form, or include `data-lpignore="true"`.

Answer (score 44):

What worked for me is having word "-search-" in the id of the form, something like `<form id="affiliate-search-form">` - and lastpass doesn't add its elements onto the form inputs. It works with something simpler like `<form id="search">` but doesn't work with `<form id="se1rch">`

Comment: Also it is suppressed if:  

- if field *name* or *class* attribute contains words "search" or "srch"
- if form *id* or *name* atttribute contains "search"
- form *role* attribute is "search"

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for password fields. Effectively, the form is still auto-filled. In my case, adding `search` as classes to both username and password disabled the asterisk button on the username field, but the password field remains as is.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that password fields are still filled when using this approach. :-(

Comment: This no longer applies to current Lastpass versions. So this answer should be removed.

Comment: adding "srch" removes the icons/autofill from text input; works as of today on Chrome and Edge

Comment: Add -search- to the id of a single input field works for me on Chrome 51, LastPass 4.1.17. Adding it to the form does not help.

Comment: I have a form called `setup_search_form` and this did, in fact, hide LastPass for me (for usernames, not for passwords).

Comment: See @CreeTar's answer below & use `type=search`

Comment: id="search" on the form hides the icons on text input boxes for me in Firefox and Chrome with the latest version of LastPass today (2020-12-18).  Good easy solution for a form that doesn't need an ID for anything else anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 19):

I know I'm late to the party here, but I found this when I was trying to stop lastpass from ruining my forms.  @takeshin is correct in that autocomplete is not enough.  I ended up doing the hack below just to hide the symbol. Not pretty, but I got rid of the icon.

If any lastpass developers are reading this, please give us an attribute to use, so we don't have to resort to stuff like this.

```
form[autocomplete="off"] input[type="text"] {
    background-position: 150% 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (even with playing with lastpass settings, which I don't actually expect my user to do anyway), though it does conflict with me setting my own `background-image` on input fields (I like to put "clear buttons" on input fields) - in which case what also worked for me was just setting `background-image` and `background-position` with `!important` to override the lastpass builtin style.

Answer (score 17):

I *think* lastpass honors the `autocomplete="off"` attribute for inputs, but I'm not 100% sure.

**EDIT** 
As others have pointed out. this only works if the user has last pass configured to honor this.

Comment: Yes it does, but not by default: https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/extension-preferences/advanced/

Comment: I can confirm lastpass does not honour `autocomplete="off"` at the form level. That just wasted me an hour of development time on an "edit user" form which appeared to display the wrong email address. The lastpass preferences have a "do not overwrite fields that are already filled" option, which helps a lot.

Comment: As Marco stated, you need to activate this behavior.
Preferences->Advanced->Respect AutoComplete=off: allow websites to disable AutoFill

Comment: how do you bypass this in lastpass?

Comment: I have not found this to be the case. LastPass in 2021 does not respect autocomplete="new-password" even with respect "autocomplete off" toggled on. you need lpignore

Answer (score 17):

For me worked either `type=search` which is kinda equal to `text` or using `role=note`.

You can check the LastPass-JavaScript but it's huge, may be you can find some workaround there, from what I saw they only check 4 input types, so `input type=search` would be one workaround:

```
!c.form && ("text" == c.type || "password" == c.type || "url" == c.type || "email" == c.type) && lpIsVisible(c))
```

Also those are the `role`-keywords they seem to ignore:

```
var c = b.getAttribute("role");
switch (c) {
case "navigation":
case "banner":
case "contentinfo":
case "note":
case "search":
case "seealso":
case "columnheader":
case "presentation":
case "toolbar":
case "directory":`
```

I checked LastPass' `onloadwff.js`, prepare for 26.960 lines of code :)

Comment: I tried all the answers above and `type=search` is only thing that works for me.

Comment: +1, it seems using `type=search` is the only way to prevent the autofill regardless of the state of the LastPass "Respect autocomplete=off" setting.

Comment: Tried adding `role="note"` or `type="search"`. None worked on latest Chrome and latest lastpass.

Comment: it seems the `lpignore` is working again, fiddle me this `https://jsfiddle.net/78z0L1sa/3/`

Comment: OMG, this is annoying, LastPass was converting my type=text password field to type=password and on this particular screen password was required to be seen, then LastPass added the site password and not the correct password without the user knowing when they saved it was changing the credentials and breaking their connections to other systems.

The lpignore, only removed the icon, the other solutions required user interaction, which isn't ideal.

Finally, changing the type to search worked; although I hate having to do this because of someone else's software.  Anyways, up-vote on this one.

Comment: fyi if `type=search` gives you the annoying webkit styling, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422689/3705667 for how to remove them.

Answer (score 11):

Add "search" to input id

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user-search"/>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Tested on latest Chrome. Its a bit of a hack, but not as potentially breaking as the others so I'll go for it.

Answer (score 11):

Bit late to the party but I have just achieved this with modifying the form with:

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="lastpass-disable-search">
```

I guess this fools lastpass into thinking that it's a search form.  This does not work for password fields however!  Lastpass ignores the name field in this case.

The only way I've managed to do this is to add the following directly at the top of the form:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <div id="lp" ><input type="text" /><input type="password" /></div><script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('lp').style.display = 'none'},75);</script>
</form>
```

It causes a nasty flicker but does remove the autofill nonsense - though it does still show the "generate password" widget.  LastPass waits until domready and then checks to see if there are any visible password fields, so it's not possible to hide or shrink the mock fields above.

Answer (score 7):

This ES6 style code was helpful for me as it added **data-lpignore** to all my input controls:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (let element of elements) {
    element.setAttribute("data-lpignore", "true");
}
```

To access a specific INPUT control, one could write something like this:

```
document.getElementById('userInput').setAttribute("data-lpignore", "true");
```

Or, you can do it by class name:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('no-last-pass');
for (let element of elements) {
    element.setAttribute("data-lpignore", "true");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For this latest October 2019 buggy release of Lastpass, this simple fix seems to be best.**

Add

`type="search"`

to your input.

The lastpass routine checks the `type` attribute to determine what to do with its autofill, and it does nothing on this html5 `type` of "search." This fix is mildly hacky, but it's a one line change that can be easily removed when they fix their buggy script.

Note: After doing this, your input might appear to be styled differently by some browsers if they pick up on the `type` attribute. If you observe this, you can prevent it from happening by setting the browser-specific CSS properties `-webkit-appearance` and `-moz-appearance` to `'none'` on your input.

Comment: There has been an element called  `data-lpignore` which you can set on true now. This will disable lastpass from autofilling

Comment: That's been around for years and is in answers all over this page. Didn't work for me. By all means, give it a go if it works and passes testing for you.

Comment: Oh, i never seen anyone complain about this. I tested it and it worked for me. I'm confused why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: It's literally the accepted answer. I don't know why you would think others haven't tried it. Check it out. But for many, many fields it doesn't stop LastPass from filling out the input.

Comment: I never said that people didn't try it. I just said that i never seen any complaints about it

Comment: Did you actually read the comments under the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me to prevent lastpass from filling a razor  @Html.EditorFor box in Chrome:

Click the active LastPass icon  in your toolbar, then go to Account Options > Extension Preferences.

On this screen check "Don't overwrite fields that are already filled" (at the bottom)

Next, click "advanced" on the left.

On this screen check "Respect AutoComplete=off: allow websites to disable Autofill".

I did not need to do anything special in my ASP cshtml form but I did have a default value in the form for the @Html.EditorFor box.

I hope this helps and works for someone.  I could not find any Razor-specific help on this problem on the web so I thought I'd add this since I figured it out with the help of above link and contributions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
[data-lastpass-icon-root], [data-lastpass-root] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Comment: @Tin Man - Um, this is the perfect example of why a code only answer is acceptable...  No explanation is needed.

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2023

While the autocomplete="no-lastpass" attribute has been suggested as a workaround in some cases, it is not guaranteed to work with all versions of LastPass or other autofill tools. Not in my case at least!

To disable LastPass autofill for certain fields, you can try using the readonly attribute and a bit of JavaScript to prevent the field from being editable.

```
<input type="text" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" onblur="this.setAttribute('readonly', true);" />
```

The readonly attribute is initially set on the input field, when the field receives focus, the readonly attribute is removed, allowing the user to enter data. Once the field loses focus, the readonly attribute is set again, disabling further editing.

This approach stopped LastPass from triggering autofill on specific fields.

Comment: Going to do some more testing but I think this is working for me.  Also did Danail's addition above.  I'll try anything! Oh, Lastpass...

Comment: @Mike I find the js way more readable and elegant in many ways :)) I don't even understand what those css are needed for.

Answer (score 1):

None of the options here (autocomplete, data-lpignore etc.) prevented LastPass from auto-filling my form fields unfortunately. I took a more sledge-hammer approach to the problem and asynchronously set the input `name` attributes via JavaScript instead. The following jQuery-dependent function (invoked from the form's onsubmit event handler) did the trick:

```
function setInputNames() {
    $('#myForm input').each(function(idx, el) {
        el = $(el);
        if (el.attr('tmp-name')) {
            el.attr('name', el.attr('tmp-name'));
        }
    });
}

$('#myForm').submit(setInputNames);
```

In the form, I simply used `tmp-name` attributes in place of the equivalent `name` attributes. Example:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/someUrl">
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <input tmp-name="password" type="password">
</form>
```

## Update 2019-03-20

I still ran into difficulties with the above on account of AngularJS depending upon form fields having `name` attributes in order for ngMessages to correctly present field validation error messages.

Ultimately, the only solution I could find to prevent LastPass filling password fields on my Password Change form was to:

1. Avoid using `input[type=password]`entirely, AND
2. to not have 'password' in the field name

Since I need to be able to submit the form normally in my case, I still employed my original solution to update the field names 'just in time'. To avoid using password input fields, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935576/how-to-make-input-type-tel-work-as-type-password/36950075#36950075) worked very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who stumbles upon this - `autocomplete="new-password"` on password field prevents LastPass from filling the password, which in combination with `data-lpignore="true"` disables it at all

Answer (score 1):

None of these work as of 10/11/2022.

What I did was add the following to a fake password field

```
<input id="disable_autofill1" name="disable_autofill1" 
  style="height:0; width:0; background:transparent;
         border:none;padding:0.3px;margin:0;display:block;" 
type="password">
```

This seems to be enough to minimize the size this element takes on screen (pretty much 0 for me) while still not triggering last pass's vicious algorithm. Put it before the real password field.

I'm sure a variant of this could be used to fool last pass for other fields where we don't need autofill or to suggest a new password.

Answer (score 0):

Tried  the -search rename but for some reason that did not work. What worked for me is the following:

1. mark form to autocomplete - autocomplete="off"
2. change the form field input type to text
3. add a new class to your css to mask the input, simulates a password field

   css bit: input.masker {
   -webkit-text-security: disc;
   }

Tried and tested in latest versions of FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`type="hidden" autocomplete="off"`

Adding this to my input worked for me. (the input also had `visibility: hidden` css).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and wanted to prevent Lastpass from filling in data in disabled email input field. I had the issue in my next js application and I used the useEffect hook to attach an event listener to the email input field, specifically listening for the input event. Initially, I tried to prevent the default behaviour using `event.preventDefault()`, but, unfortunately, this method didn't work. As a workaround, I resolved the issue by reassigning the initial value whenever the event listener was triggered.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const emailField = document.getElementById("emailInput");
    emailField.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault(); 
      emailField.value = user.email;
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The LastPass icon is a late arrival to the DOM.
I came up with this to deal with it using jQuery/JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('div[data-lastpass-icon-root]').css({'display': 'none'});
  }, 140);
});
```

Comment: You may have to start out with a higher number than 140 to see it happen (eg 300).
Also, use Chrome inspector to see if div[data-lastpass-icon-root] is in the DOM... maybe LastPass changes the name every so often.

Answer (score -1):

**Update NOV 2021**

I have noticed that all LastPass widgets are wrapped in div of class css-1obar3y.

```
div.css-1obar3y {
  display: none!important;
}
```

But yeah, it's probably a bad way to go this way.

Comment: Friendly heads up: I wouldn't expect this to be a reliable solution. The class name appears to be generated and likely to change at any future point.

Comment: ...and also to be different for different installed version. 1/10, would not use.