# How to prevent LastPass (chrome extension) from auto-filling input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, lastpass

I want to prevent LastPass from filling out an input field on my site. I'm using AngularJS and HTML5, and the extension is autofilling the following input field. This field is a search field inside my page; it's not a login page.

```
<input id="search-publishers-box" type="text" placeholder="Search Publishers" data-ng-model="publishersSearchQuery.name" class="search-field-text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

What can I do to prevent LastPass from doing its autofill? I've tried to change the `placeholder`, the `model`, adding `autocomplete="off"`, and changed the `id` of the input field.

None have worked at all for me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Why?

Comment: because this field is a search field inside my page, it's not a login page, it's a filter page that for no reason fill in with the user name that logged in and filter the page table

Comment: I might just hide any other inputs from a page with login. ||| Less then a minute of googling gave me this  https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/extension-preferences/advanced Apparently the autocomplete off should work, but it needs to be enabled in last pass settings from the users side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop LastPass filling out a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form)

Comment: If I asked LastPass to autofill a site then that is what I want. Why would you do this? This is a terrible user experience.

Comment: @AdrianBrand a terrible user experience is when you have a disabled field that is bound to your datasource for user information and you just renamed a user on accident because a field that shouldn't be editable at all just got overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on this, and usually what I do to solve the autofill problems (yes, they're obscure but they do happen) – I usually watch the fields for changes. Since you're using `AngularJS`, its pretty easy to do with `$watch`, or if you're using `jQuery`, just use `.change`

And then, whenever there's a change of more than one character at one time, you can assume that its autofill and not someone typing.

Note that this breaks if someone decides to paste into the field.

Another workaround is to allow change on the field only when there's a `keypress`.

**EDIT** [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RkepV/)

Comment: how can i know if it's more than 1 change at a time? can you paste a code example?

Comment: @LiadLivnat I've added the link to a fiddle showing the idea.

Comment: My issue was lastpass changing a field to the same -1 char, so not a perfect solution

Comment: given the second workaround however it seems to work well

Answer (score 13):

Put this attribute in your input element you wish to not have LP alter.

```
data-lpignore="true"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, per LastPass documentation: https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=10512

Comment: This removes the icon but does not prevent autocomplete I'm afraid.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore - I'm banging my head up against it at the moment.

See this reddit thread also: https://www.reddit.com/r/Lastpass/comments/z1jno4/recent_update_html_to_disable_autofill/

Comment: @GusBus it looks like LastPass has a user setting now to "Respect Autocomplete=off" [Source](https://support.lastpass.com/help/how-do-i-prevent-fields-from-being-filled-automatically)

Comment: @KeeganTeetaert that doesn't solve the problem because I don't want my users to have to configure their lastpass settings just for it not be be annoying.

I ended up solving this problem by watching for changes to the DOM around my input fields and selectively deleting them - happy to share source code (DM me - I don't want anyone at LastPass to see it because they'll just figure out a workaround)

Answer (score 3):

Try using type="search" instead.. which is an invalid type... which will fallback to type text...

[Stop LastPass filling out a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form)

Comment: This is actually VERY good suggestion. Much easier then keypress hacks.

Comment: This is what worked for me here in october 2019 with lastpass shipping another buggy release. And by the way `search` is not an invalid type for `input` in html5. It's just a type that at this point Lastpass does nothing with.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the previous answer from @nawlbergs helped to solve the issue. The `data-lpignore="true"` isn't helping anymore (probably they've updated their logic as this solution is no more present in their FAQs as well).

LastPass seems to only work with the inputs with `type="text"` and `type="password"` to fill the passwords (these are the only input types one can configure in the form fields in LastPass entries). Whenever you're using some other type that's valid (unlike @nawlbergs suggested) but isn't a `"text"`.

That said, the `type="search"` helps, as well as the rest of the possible valid `type` values. It's just that the `type="search"` has the same `text`-like behaviour and can be used freely anywhere:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search

Answer (score 0):

use this

global:

```
[data-lastpass-icon-root] {
display: none !important;
}
```

specific container:

```
#div_container_to_disable_lastpass [data-lastpass-icon-root] {
display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).