# LastPass Chrome extension throwing error and preventing click events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, lastpass

I'm registering a simple click event like seen below:

```
$('.block--hero').on('click', '*[data-target-id]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
            console.log('clicked');
});
```

Frequently, but not always, when I click on the interface element, I'll receive the following console error that I've identified as belonging to the `LastPass` extension for Google Chrome.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined onloadwff.js:726
    lp_docinfoFromEvent onloadwff.js:726
    icon_click_handler onloadwff.js:727
    (anonymous function) onloadwff.js:139
```

When I receive this error, the `clicked` message wasn't logged to the console. Essentially, the click event returned `false`.

Normally, I'd just disable the extension and forget about it, but `LastPass` is a pretty popular extension, and I'd like to somehow guarantee my intended behaviour. Users aren't going to know it's their extension causing the problem - only that the site doesn't work.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You should probably get in touch with [LastPass support](https://lastpass.com/supportticket.php), too.

Comment: Thanks, I've submitted a ticket, but it looks like non-premium support tickets have a 5-day turnaround due to Heartbleed issues.... which means I'll get a real response to this in 15 days or so. :(

Comment: Did you get any reply from LastPass? I am having some trouble here, similar problem – and LastPass simply ignore.

Comment: Any news about it? @AaronSilber

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this bug from the code you shared and I have LastPass (Version: 4.3.0) installed in my Google Chrome (63.0.3239.84) https://jsfiddle.net/08sdf58t/

Comment: Hey everyone — I keep getting notifications about this ticket from 2014 and I wanted to state for the record that I never received a satisfactory support response from Lastpass. I've also haven't encountered this issue in the 3 years since submitting this question. So I guess I'll just delete this. :D

Comment: If you don't want to lose (more than half) your rep, you could just flag to close your question as "off-topic: a problem that can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: the problem seems to be back

Answer (score 10):

[Uplifted from my comment on suggestion of [Muhamed Cicak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5911206/muhamed-cicak) and to draw more prominence.]

Lastpass has a 'Never URLs' option on the account admin page where you can tell it to ignore a URL - useful if you want Lastpass awake but not start interfering with your forms.

To access it:

- Open your Lastpass vault
- Open Account Settings
- On the top of the window there is a list of options - select 'Never URLs'
- There are options for 'Never Add Site', 'Never Fill Forms' and 'Never Do Anything'. Use the Add button to add a URL.

[EDIT] Additionally there is an accepted answer for page authors in a [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form) which says to add

```
data-lpignore="true"
```

to tell lastpass to ignore it.

Comment: I had the same issue. By just adding the 'Never Do Anything' option mentioned already did the work. Thanks :)

Comment: This helped me to login to openai services again. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this today. It seems to be related with lastpass not being able to find the username and password fields. I found [this post](https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=274205) on the last pass forms. 
From one of the users:

> Update: I fixed this error by renaming the ids of my fields to reg_username, reg_password, login_username, and login_password.

I did this and the error has not shown itself.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: Lastpass has a 'Never URLs' option on the account admin page where you can tell it to ignore a URL - useful if you want Lastpass awake but not interfering.

Comment: @MuhamedCicak - further update re answer if you are the HTML page author.