# Lastpass changing username

Tags: lastpass

I have a form that username gets pre-populated from the backend. When the page loads, the username is shown in the `username` field. When lastpass loads, it changes the `username` to the username that is saved on the lastpass. It looks like a bug that lastpass overwrites the username when it has a value. Is there a way to prevent this?

[image]

In the above video, pre defined username is `baz@qux.com`. After lastpass is loaded, it changes to `foo@bar.com`.

PS. I'm the developer. I am looking for a way to prevent this from happening for my users.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
data-lpignore="true"
```

On your html element.

According to lastpass documentation:

> To prevent LastPass icons on your website or application from appearing on non-desired fields, add 'data-lpignore'=true attribute to your form fields, this will prevent LastPass icons from being generated in this particular locations.

Source: https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=10512

Comment: I disagree with using a Lastpass specific solution.  Ideally you'd use the HTML standard `autocomplete ="off"` and Lastpass would respect it (along with all other password managers). 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: Mark, thanks for answer but what you suggested only removes the icon. Lastpass still changes the username value.

Comment: @Ben Lastpass still changes the input with autocomplete="off".

Comment: @Ben https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form