# Force LastPass to prompt user to update their username after they change it

Tags: html, forms, lastpass

We're running into an issue that has been asked about before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148685/lastpass-changing-username) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form) - after a user changes their email, LastPass will autofill the old email on our settings page. Since there seems to be no good way to prevent that from happening, we'd like to force LastPass to ask the user if they want to change their username after they submit the form on the settings page. Are there any form field naming conventions or other hints we can put in the DOM to do this?