# TextareaAutosize With Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using [react-textarea-autosize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-textarea-autosize) and [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik)  and I am wondering how to properly hook the change events of formik to TextareaAutosize?

```
   <Formik
          initialValues={{
            description: ''
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({

          })}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, setErrors }) => {
            console.log('v', values)

          }}
          render={props => (
            <Form autoComplete="off">
              <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Description</label>
                <div className="control">
                  <TextareaAutosize
                    className="input"
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                    name="description"
                    value={props.values.description}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

            </Form>
          )}
```

So when I do an onSubmit, I do see the data that is entered in the textarea but when I do an "enter" in the textarea I get these errors

```
onloadwff.js:71 Assertion failed: Input argument is not an HTMLInputElement
getFormProfile @ onloadwff.js:71
setFieldValue @ onloadwff.js:71
formKeydownListener @ onloadwff.js:71
onloadwff.js:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at e.setFieldValue (onloadwff.js:71)
    at HTMLFormElement.formKeydownListener (onloadwff.js:71)
setFieldValue @ onloadwff.js:71
formKeydownListener @ onloadwff.js:71
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

funny, I had this as well, it is not related to Formik whatsoever, `onloadwff.js` is related to **lastpass**, and this error is thrown from the chrome extension :]

Comment: oh, would never had thought it would be this? I wonder why lastpass it trying to hook to the textarea. I tried in private mode without any plugins and I don't see the error so it seems to check out.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error from the Lastpass plugin/extension.

I found some ways to solve this issue. One is via the Lastpass plugin/extension itself.

### Via Lastpass

#### Add an exception on this URL

1. Click extension and go to "Open my vault"
2. Navigate to Account Settings
3. Go to the "Never URLs" tab
4. Add "http://localhost" (or the URL you are using) and for Type choose "Never Do Anything"

### Via code

If you want to solve it via code (so it wouldn't happen for anyone, in case you are deploying the app to production), there are other ways.

#### Add `data-lpignore="true"` attribute to the form element

Example:

```
<form data-lpignore="true"> 
  ... 
</form>
```

In your case, the form would be something like this:

```
            <Form autoComplete="off" data-lpignore="true">
              <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Description</label>
                <div className="control">
                  <TextareaAutosize
                    className="input"
                    onChange={props.handleChange}
                    onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                    name="description"
                    value={props.values.description}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

            </Form>
```

#### Stop the event propagation

##### Event Listener

Create a listener for the `keydown` event and stop the propagation there for the `Enter` key (which seems to be the one Lastpass listens to) with `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleHitEnter, true);
    
function handleHitEnter(event: globalThis.KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event && event.key === "Enter") {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

I have also seen people stopping the propagation with event handlers, but in my case, nothing worked because LastPass would handle the `keydown` event first before propagating to any handlers. But I will add it here as another option

##### Event Handler

###### Event Handler for Angular:

```
<textarea matInput matTextareaAutosize
 formControlName="description"
 (keydown.enter)="enterEventHandler($event)"
></textarea>
```

And the enterEventHandler like this:

```
enterEventHandler($event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
  $event.stopPropagation()
  // handle form submission
}
```

##### Event handler for React:

```
<textarea
  className="input"
  name="description"
  onKeyDown={event => enterEventHandler(event)}
/>
```

```
function enterEventHandler(event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
  if (event && event.key === "Enter") {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

References:

1. [Error when hitting enter... Github discussion](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/351)
2. [Stop LastPass filling out a form StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form/44984917#44984917)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Form, Formik, Field as FormikField } from "formik";
...
const TextAreaField = ({maxRows, minRows, ...props}) => {
   return (
    <FormikField
      {...props}
    >
      {({ field }) => <TextareaAutosize maxRows={maxRows} minRows={} {...field} />}
    </FormikField>
   );
}
...
const MyForm = () => {
   ...
   return (
    <Formik
        initialValues={{
          ...
        }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <Form>
         <TextAreaField
           name="about"
           maxRows={maxRows} 
           minRows={minRows}
         />
      </Form>
    </Formik>
   );
};
```

It works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).