# Is there a way to detect if the LastPass extension is working on the website (in React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, lastpass

I have a password input with the eye symbol to show the text, it works fine, however, It lies exactly when the LastPass box is laying.

My goal is to move the eye symbol a bit to the left if the extension is on, but I **don't want to disable it completely** because it can be useful and for other reasons.

Current behavior:

[image]

Expected behavior:

[image]

Is there a way to detect something like this?

**UPDATE**
Something like in `material-ui`: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments

Comment: Perhaps the eye symbol could be moved *after* the input element? I'm assuming LastPass adds the symbol to the *end of the input element*, so placing it outside the input element would solve the overlap.

Comment: But to help with the actual question - does the LastPass symbol have a unique classname or ID?

Comment: It sits on the current input, it adds a background to it. therefore, you can't identify it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kbJeaAWS

Comment: I could to that, but then the eye would be outside the input, and I don't really want that..

Comment: Does this work? [How can I tell if my website visitors are using LastPass or other password managers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/92237)

Comment: Yes, it would be outside the `<input>` but you could style it so that it *looks like* it's inside the input.

Comment: @cbr Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since I didn't get any answers, I went with @cbr 's solution which is to trim the input width and make it look like the eye is in the input.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form (sorry about three years late)