# How to prevent browser extension icons (Last Pass) from appearing in fields in React Apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins, lastpass

In my web app I have a create-user page, and users with the Last Pass extension in their browsers get Last Pass icons appearing in some fields. I want to prevent these icons from appearing.

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954944/stop-lastpass-filling-out-a-form) that for straight css, one can do

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" data-lpignore="true">
```

but I don't know how to replicate that inside a React App.

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML attributes directly in React 16+, referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31273478/11258480).

If you *are* using a form library, check if they expose refs and add attributes using them, *or* (discouraged) add a `useEffect` hook or `componentDidMount` function and modify attribute using `document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('data-lpignore', 'true')`