# Prevent fields from being auto-filled by LastPass Extension

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, lastpass

I have a form component used for searching, but LastPass keeps treating it as an email / username field and auto populating it.

I've looked at past discussions on StackExchange, and the accepted answers no longer seem valid. I have also tried following their documentation, but as soon as the code is compiled and deployed, LastPass stops honoring the `data-lpignore="true"` tag.

https://support.lastpass.com/help/how-do-i-prevent-fields-from-being-filled-automatically

The app is using a BootstrapVue form input component, and `hidden` isn't an acceptable form input type. My code looks like this.

```
  <b-col cols="9">
    <b-form-group
      label="Filter"
      label-cols="2"
      label-align="right"
      style="width: 100%"
    >
      <b-form-input
        v-model="filter"
        data-lpignore="true"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Type to Search"
      />
    </b-form-group>
  </b-col>
```

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input

I've tried a good assortment of suggestions in the comments, but I can't seem to find any that work. Any ideas?

Comment: it must be the name or type of the input looking like username/email would help if you showed the hrml, change the type to `type="search"` and for sure dont have things like `autocomplete="email"` on the field https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete use `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Lawrence. I've added my code. I had the `type=search` bit, which would work under normal circumstances, but apparently LastPass broke their latest build, or at least made breaking changes without changing usage in the documentation. https://community.logmein.com/t5/LastPass-Support-Discussions/Did-You-Break-data-lpignore-true/m-p/299069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently they cut the `data-lpignore="true"` rule and revived old `id includes the term "search"` rule from 2015. Someone needs to update the documentation on their website. Here's my fix.

```
<b-form-input
  id="type-search"
  data-lpignore="true"
  v-model="filter"
  type="search"
  placeholder="Type to Search"
/>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921628/13201277

Comment: It is driving me nuts there is no solid/working fix for this in 2023. I tried various things from other SO posts but nothing worked. I tried adding variations of "-search-" to my <asp:TextBox /> but it triggers some error (maybe a research word or something?). For now I'm having to disable autofill on all sites via the LastPass global extension settings. =/  https://support.lastpass.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=lastpass&topicId=LastPass/disable-autofill.html&_LANG=enus