# How do I remove the X in the default twentyfifteen search box theme?

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

How do I remove the X in the end of the search box? 
I added my own search button, and I don't want the X at all. 
Using wordpress 4.1 
twentyfifteen theme.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove all default Webkit search field styling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421551/how-do-i-remove-all-default-webkit-search-field-styling)

Comment: Yey works thank you !

Comment: I didn't know it's a webkit so google didl't find anything relevant for me

Comment: Also for IE -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007655/remove-ie10s-clear-field-x-button-on-certain-inputs