# sorting not working as per requirement in angular-dataTables

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I have an issue in my project. I am using angular dataTables. While sorting, if I have data for one column as `1.4`, `1.5`, `10`, `2.4`
I need to return it as `1.4`, `1.5`, `2.4`, `10`. But I am getting as `1.4`, `1.5`, `10`, `2.4`. It is considering only first character I suppose.

Is there any solution for this? Below is the code snippet.

```js
$scope.dtOptions = { paging: false, searching: false };
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [

];
```

i am not sure what i have to write in column defs for sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a value somewhere in the column converts to an illegal number and by that turning the auto detected type into alpha sorting. Force the sorting type of the column by setting `type` - `num` is for number :

```
$scope.dtColumns = DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(0)
                                  .withOption('type', 'num') //<---
                                  .withTitle('#')
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/teKt4xgTWD98IfBc2dNb?p=preview**

Try comment `.withOption('type', 'num')` out ..

---

If you wonder about the syntax it is the same as

```
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
   { targets: 0, type: 'num', title: '#' }
];
```

Comment: i have used natural plugin and instead of num i have passed natural because i am having numbers, decimals as well as alpha numerics

Comment: @sn, yes - this is even better.

Comment: @sri, this is an CSS issue, you can easily prevent it - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421551/how-do-i-remove-all-default-webkit-search-field-styling and similar answers.

Comment: Hey @sri - sounds you have some code that initialise the dataTable both upon ready and when a tab is shown ...? Look for the `destroy` option.

Comment: thanks david for your reply. its because of flaw in code. function in controller is executing multiple times where it is destroying and initializing data table. i fixed the code so it will hit function only once and initialize data table also only once