# Next.JS/Material UI : How to remove the webkit-search-clear-button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm currently struggling to find how to make disappear the webkit-search-close-button from an input type search in a NextJS component that uses Material UI.

Here's is the return part of the component :

```js
return (
    <>
      <h2>Choisissez une boutique et un horaire :</h2>
      <FormControl className={input}>
        <TextField
          type='search'
          label="Département ou code postal"
          required={true}
          helperText={error && "Veuillez entrer un format de département ou de code postal valide"}
          error={error}
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton className={button} onClick={handleSearchClick}>
                  <img src="./search.svg" alt="Rechercher" />
                </IconButton>
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          onKeyDown={handleEnterPress}
        />
      </FormControl>
      {filteredAgenceList === null ? <p>Aucun résultat n'a été trouvé</p>
        : pendingSearch && loading ? <p>Recherche en cours ...</p>
          : filteredAgenceList.length > 0 ?
            <List className={list}>{filteredAgenceList.map((agence, index) => renderAgence(agence, index))}</List>
            : <p>Seules les boutiques prenant en charge votre motif de rendez-vous s'afficheront.</p>
      }
      <div className={navButton}>
        <BackButton step={1} onClick={backButtonClick} />
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        p {
          color: #555555;
          margin-top: 5px;
        }
        /* clears the 'X' from Internet Explorer */
        input::-ms-clear {
          display: none; 
          width : 0; 
          height: 0; 
        }
        input::-ms-reveal {
          display: none;
          width : 0;
          height: 0;
        }
  
        /* clears the 'X' from Chrome */
          
        input::-webkit-search-cancel-button { 
          -webkit-appearance: none;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
```

As you can see just above, I tried to hide the clear button in IE and Chrome, but as you can see, the input is still displaying it.

[image]

Is there a way to remove this clear button, maybe with a Material UI property ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422689/10237430

Comment: This is what I tried before posting my issue, and it didn't solved my problem.
This part of CSS is from the link you send, a little bit modified because I just need to hide the search cancel button
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}